# JavaScript object property not supported in IE?

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6

I have the following code that works perfectly fine in Chrome etc, but doesn't work in IE 11:

```
var fieldName="UserField";
var fieldValue="update value here..."

var obj = {
             id: 123,
             [fieldName]: fieldValue
           };
var message="The field ["+ fieldName +"] will be updated with the value of ["+ obj[fieldName] +"]";
```

[Here is a plunker that shows the problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/XZeIaoVSLmMlXa56oGGt?p=info)

Since the variable is dynamic, I can't just hard-code it in.

Any idea how I can get it to work in IE?

Comment: Reference the property outside the object declaration, so `obj[fieldName] = fieldValue;`, because IE

Comment: May I know what IE version are you using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE does not support [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

You could take a classic [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```js
var fieldName = "UserField",
    fieldValue = "update value here...",
    obj = { id: 123 };

obj[fieldName] = fieldValue;

var message = "The field [" + fieldName + "] will be updated with the value of [" + obj[fieldName] + "]";

console.log(message);
```

Comment: Perfect! sometimes the obvious eludes us!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, they're not supported in IE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Computed property names in objects are [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) in Internet Explorer (but they are supported by the newer Edge browsers).

You might need to take that into account if you are working with lots of IE users.